# Paypal Invoice not sending VAT and Item Name to customer

Tags: php, paypal, oscommerce

I am having an Oscommerce website. I am sending the VAT and Item Name to paypal and on successfull purchase it is sending invoice to customer where there are no option of VAT Added and Item Name Purchased. Can you tell me why this is happening? I am doing it on Live Paypal

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your VAT up on your PayPal account for items that you are selling?

If not please follow the steps below. If you have already and it is now showing please review your settings to ensure that there are no changes.

You can customize the VAT rate charged on your sales from your PayPal account. Your shopping cart software can take this rate and add it to the final price of your sales.

PayPal won’t charge VAT on your payments unless you select this option and specify a rate.

To select this setting on your account:

Log in to your PayPal account

- Click ‘Profile’ near the top of the page.
- Click ‘My selling    preferences’. Under ‘Selling online’ click ‘Update’ next to VAT.
- Click ‘Add New Sales Tax’ in the Domestic or International section to    add a new rate.
- Enter the rate and click ‘Continue’.

Comment: I didnot setup VAT on my paypal account. I am sending VAT to paypal checkout and it shows on the left handside on doing transaction. Under My Selling preferences it is showing  "Sales tax" no VAT

Comment: Then I think your answer is here ->  https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_cart_overrides_outside

Comment: I already did that but still it is not sending VAT on invoice from paypal side